# ASP.Net MVC - forms authentication using an external URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

Our organization has a central solution for forms authentication.  I am trying to implement an ASP.Net MVC app that uses this external URL - and it worked till RC! was released...

Here's what's happening

In an ActionAttribute Extension

I check for s session var
   if not found
       check for a request data chuck
            if found, set the session var
            if not found - redirect to external URL
   if found
    continue.

The trouble is that till I updated to RC1, this worked. Since then, so many requests are being sent to the external URL that it detects a DoS attack and shuts me out!

I removed the redirection code and replaced it with the web.config changes for Forms Auth - and the same thing happened...

Comment: ActionAttribute or AuthorizeAttribute?  A little code would help, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating a static dictionary of requesting IPs, and dropping duplicate requests from the same IP.  Not a very nice solution - so if anyone figures out a better solution - let me know.

Comment: As it turns out, the issue was with the fact that validation, depending on the content of the token, got rid of it - without any exception being throw.... :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Microsoft Geneva](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx) instead of attempting to roll your own authentication provider?

Comment: becuse it is out of my hands - when i run my own company - I will have that option, unfortunately, as a good corporate citizen I need to use what already exists and is used by all other applications in the org...

Do you have any real answers?

Comment: I don't think you've really considered what I said, if you don't consider it a "real answer." Geneva does what you want.

Comment: Downloaded Geneva white paper.  Read it.  Requires server side change = Out of my hands.  Not a real solution in this case.  Not trying to hurt you ego or anything, but I need a client side solution without changing the architecture completely... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CODE:

```
public class MyAuthenticate : ActionFilterAttribute
    {        
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["user"] == null)
            {
                using (Authenticator dp = new Authenticator())
                {
                    MyUser mu;
                    string data = string.Empty;
                    try
                    {
                        data = filterContext.HttpContext.Request["Data"];
                    }
                    catch { };

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
                    {
                        mu = dp.Redeem(data);
                        if (mu.authenticated)
                        {                            
                            filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Clear();
                            AuthenticatedUser user = new AuthenticatedUser(mu);
                            filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Add("user", user);
                            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserId, false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("MY EXTERNAL URL GOES HERE!!");

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("MY EXTERNAL URL GOES HERE!!");
                    }
                }
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: It dosen't matter if I use this code or Just set the Forms auth in the web config with an external URL - the same behavior is observed- keep getting several hits to the external url (more than 30/sec).